# How can we define a Genereic List just giving the textual class name?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, reflection

I would like to know how to define a generic list just giving the textual class name and using System.Type as shown in the example below :

```
Type entity_type = Type.GetType("Entities.Human, Entities");

List<entity_type> a = new List<entity_type>();
```

Comment: Do you need the *variable* to be of type `List<entity_type>`? If so, then C# does not support this. If you are OK with having the variable of type `object` or `IList`, .. then this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should get type of generic list and then make it parametrized with your enity type:

```
Type entity_type = Type.GetType("Entities.Human, Entities");
Type list_type = typeof(List<>);
Type entity_list_type = list_type.MakeGenericType(entity_type);
```

Creating instance of list:

```
IList entity_list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(entity_list_type);
entity_list.Add(entity);
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergey but i want to know how i will use "entity_list_type" if I want to add some objects with "entity_type" ? thank you for your help again

Comment: @AbdelatifLatrach you can use non-generic `IList` interface for that

Answer (score 1):

```
var type = Type.GetType("Entities.Human, Entities");
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```